# Camera Stream Muliplexer

Tags: usb-cam, ros-kinetic, camera, image-transport

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI Everyone,

The robot platform I am working on has 6 cameras onboard with different views.
The Coms system only has the bandwidth for one of these views, what is the best (quickest/easiest) way to select one of the streams and publish it as a single topic.

I assume using the image transport system would be a good place to start?

Regards,
Nick

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/281457/camera-stream-muliplexer/) by [skipper762](https://answers.ros.org/users/33502/skipper762/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-01-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2018-02-01**:
That seems like a good answer to me, @gvdhoorn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does your robot have onboard processing running? Is the 'Coms system' a bridge between the system on on the robot and your 'base station'? If so, [topic_mux](http://wiki.ros.org/topic_tools/mux) could help here.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-02-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [skipper762](https://answers.ros.org/users/33502/skipper762/) on 2018-02-01**:
There is an Intel NUC running as the main processor, so plenty of processing power.
You are right, I didn't explain the situation very well.
The robot is teleoperated over a non-ROS comumincation link to the base station.
It seems like topic_mux is perfect for my needs, thank you very much

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-02**:
Do realise that the NUC will then subscribe to all 6 cameras, but only republish one topic, that your base station node(s) will subscribe to. Depending on what sort of cameras these are, that could be very wasteful of cpu resources. Be sure to look at the `lazy` parameter.